# SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-blade

My code is like this :

```
<multiple-photo-product :product="{{ isset($product) ? $product : '' }}"></multiple-photo-product>
```

When the code runs it throws an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in

But if the code is like this:

```
 <multiple-photo-product product="{{ isset($product) ? $product : '' }}"></multiple-photo-product>
```

It doesn't throw an error.

I add `:`, so that the data is sent as an object.

If it does not use `:`, the data is sent as a string.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is `isset($product)` client side code or server side code?

Comment: @Bert Evans, server side code

Comment: Is the error server side or client side? If it's client side, what is actually rendered as a result of your ternary?

Comment: I do not think you are allowed to use interpolation inside of bindings. Try `:product="isset($product) ? $product : '' "`

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? Use your browser's *"View source"* option

Comment: I add `{{..}}`, because I use laravel framework

Comment: @Bert Evans, The error is client side. It's an object

Comment: Can you add the rendered HTML including the rendered object to your question please?

Comment: @TrendingNews You need to provide more information about your problem.... For instance, <multiple-photo-product> component exists inside a (Laravel?) view, or inside another vue component?

Comment: @ira, it exist inside a view laravel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that if the php variable `$product` is not set (i.e equals to `null` or `""`), then Vue will try to bind the prop `:product` with `''` which ultimately results to an error (like trying to make a `:product=""` bind)

Try the following:

```
<multiple-photo-product :product="{{ isset($product) ? $product : '""' }}"></multiple-photo-product>
```

Notice the double quotes `""` surrounded by the single quotes. This will say to Vue to bind the `product` prop with an empty string, in case php's `$product` variable is not set.

Please also have a look [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3969). You may find it helpful. The key point to recall is that `v-bind` expects *valid javascript expressions*, that is the interpolated value (i.e. whatever is inside the Blade's curly braces `{{}}`) must be a valid javascript expression too

Answer (score -3):

In VueJS2, the attribute properties with `:` don't need the `{{ }}`. In your case, the ternary is like that :

```
<multiple-photo-product product="isset($product) ? $product : ''"></multiple-photo-product>
```

Source : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

> Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes, instead use a v-bind directive

Comment: The {{}} is a server side interpolation. He is using laravel.